# In GNOME, can I move icons from the notification tray to the system bar at the top of the screen?

Tags: gnome, gui, notifications

For some of my commonly-used applications, GNOME places their notification icons into this small tray at the bottom-left of my screen.

Here's how it looks expanded:

[image]

It's normally tucked away with about 1 or 2px protruding and can be expanded on click, but this has a major drawback: when it's expanded, it takes up usable screen space, covering up part of the window beneath it; when it's retracted, I can't see notifications raised by those applications.

Is there a way to move these icons into the system bar at the top of the screen, where they're permanently visible without covering usable screen space? I've looked through both the tweak tool and the `dconf` editor, but haven't found anything that affects this (or, at least, nothing that seems obvious by name or description, or isn't flagged as deprecated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through `gnome-tweak-tool`, you can install the `topicons plus` extension.

It does just that; moves the icons to the top bar, with a few options to get them just right for your setup.

Here's a direct link for you convenience: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: if you need to know your Gnome version first `sudo apt-cache show gnome-shell | grep Version`